# How do I find the path of CUDA on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, pytorch, libtorch

I have pytorch installed and working no problem, making use of the GPU. While trying to install Libtorch, I kept getting errors like:

```
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
```

I can't find where this path is. I will edit the post with the output of commands.

CMake error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
-- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) 

Caffe2: CUDA cannot be found.  Depending on whether you are building Caffe2
  or a Caffe2 dependent library, the next warning / error will give you more
  info
```

output of `sudo find / |grep nvcc`:

```
/usr/local/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindCUDA/run_nvcc.cmake
/usr/local/boost_1_80_0/boost/predef/compiler/nvcc.h
/usr/local/boost_1_80_0/boost/config/compiler/nvcc.hpp
/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindCUDA/run_nvcc.cmake
/usr/include/boost/predef/compiler/nvcc.h
/usr/include/boost/config/compiler/nvcc.hpp
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/125/gvfs’: Permission denied
/home/xxx/.local/share/Trash/files/libtorch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Modules_CUDA_fix/upstream/FindCUDA/run_nvcc.cmake
/home/xxx/.local/share/xmake/modules/core/tools/nvcc.lua
/home/xxx/.local/share/xmake/modules/detect/tools/find_nvcc.lua
/home/xxx/.local/share/xmake/modules/detect/tools/nvcc
/home/xxx/.local/share/xmake/modules/detect/tools/nvcc/has_flags.lua
/home/xxx/Documents/xxx/mongo/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Modules_CUDA_fix/upstream/FindCUDA/run_nvcc.cmake
/home/xxx/Documents/pytorch/libtorch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Modules_CUDA_fix/upstream/FindCUDA/run_nvcc.cmake
/home/xxx/Documents/mongo/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Modules_CUDA_fix/upstream/FindCUDA/run_nvcc.cmake
/home/xxx/Documents/xxx/xx/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Modules_CUDA_fix/upstream/FindCUDA/run_nvcc.cmake
find: ‘/home/midas/mydrive’: Permission denied
/home/xxx/git/xxx-projects/xx/Script/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Modules_CUDA_fix/upstream/FindCUDA/run_nvcc.cmake
/home/xxx/git/midas-engine/cicd-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Modules_CUDA_fix/upstream/FindCUDA/run_nvcc.cmake
/home/xxx/git/xxx-xx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Modules_CUDA_fix/upstream/FindCUDA/run_nvcc.cmake
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/<large-string>/diff/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Modules_CUDA_fix/upstream/FindCUDA/run_nvcc.cmake
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/<large-string>/diff/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Modules_CUDA_fix/upstream/FindCUDA/run_nvcc.cmake
```

Comment: When did you get that error?  I guess the message is from `Caffe2/Modules_CUDA_fix/upstream/FindCUDA.cmake`, which needs to set `-D CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/your/cuda/path` when calling cmake.

Comment: I have added the excat error message while cmakeing. I don't actually know my cuda toolkit path. I don't want to install anything on this machine.

Comment: Try `which nvcc`, `find / |grep nvcc` or something alike to locate cuda path.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the output to my post

Comment: The default path in ubuntu should be /usr/local/cuda, if not modified. In your setting, I guess that CUDA toolkit is not yet installed on your computer. Does nvidia-smi command work?

Comment: Nvidia-smi works